# Using an Interface in PHP

Tags: php, interface

Are there best practices for when it's appropriate to use an [interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php)?

Does this use much more resources than just having the code directly in a class, instead of creating this "layer"?

Comment: Use more resources?  Do you mean CPU time? disk space? RAM?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380720/php-interfaces-how-are-they-usable-in-practice/7380735#7380735 for examples of when interfaces are useful

Comment: It's a language feature. Learn for what it is good for. Compare with `sleep`, you only use it when you need it, not just to wait because you can wait (for no apparent reason).

Comment: @Time Cooper - more CPU time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces are contracts that you typically expose so others can fulfill the contracts in your code.  Unless you plan on having others work with your interfaces, or you plan to make multiple classes yourself to fullfull the interface you're making a lot of work for yourself for little benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You would use an interface to define a contract that implementing classes must abide by.

You would use this in object oriented programming / object oriented design to adhere to [SOLID](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) principles.

Interfaces are relevant to almost all of these principles.